# Error: ReferenceError: getUnreadEmails is not defined

Tags: javascript, react-native

please when I call the method getNumberOfUnreadEmails in the App.js i have this error : 
YellowBox.js:67 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: ReferenceError: getUnreadEmails is not defined
Error: ReferenceError: getUnreadEmails is not defined
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/16f9ab34-0ee8-4ee2-8319-83df5fb4878a:102968:19
    at tryCallOne (blob:http://localhost:8081/16f9ab34-0ee8-4ee2-8319-83df5fb4878a:31155:14)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/16f9ab34-0ee8-4ee2-8319-

expect :
give me the number of unread Messages

AzureInstance.js

```
 export default class AzureInstance {
constructor(credentials) {
this.authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common';
this.authorize_endpoint = '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
this.redirect_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient';
this.token_endpoint ='/oauth2/v2.0/token';
this.client_id = credentials.client_id;
this.client_secret = credentials.client_secret;
this.scope = credentials.scope;
this.token = {};

// function binding
this.getConfig = this.getConfig.bind(this);
this.setToken = this.setToken.bind(this);
this.getToken = this.getToken.bind(this);
this.getUserInfo = this.getUserInfo.bind(this);
this.getUnreadEmails=this.getUnreadEmails.bind(this);
this.getNumberOfUnreadEmails=this.getNumberOfUnreadEmails.bind(this);
//this.getRequest=this.getRequest.bind(this);
}

getConfig(){
return {
authority: this.authority,
authorize_endpoint: this.authorize_endpoint,
token_endpoint: this.token_endpoint,
client_id: this.client_id,
client_secret: this.client_secret,
redirect_uri: this.redirect_uri,
scope: this.scope,
}
}

setToken(token){
this.token = token;
}

getToken(){
return this.token;
}
getUserInfo()
{
try{
return this.getRequest("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
}
catch(err){
throw err;
}
}

getNumberOfUnreadEmails()
{
return getUnreadEmails().value.length();
}
getUnreadEmails()
{
try{
return this.getRequest("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=isRead ne true");
}
catch(err){
throw err;
}
}

getRequest(req) {
if (this.token === undefined){
throw new Error("Access token is undefined, please authenticate using Auth first");
}

return fetch(req, {
headers: {
'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.token.accessToken,
}
}).then(response => {
// return blob object
return response.json()
})
.then(response => {
// read blob object back to json
return response
}).catch(err => {
// incase of error reject promise
throw new Error(err);
});
}
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,Text,StyleSheet,Picker} from 'react-native';
import {View} from 'react-native-webview';

import {AzureInstance, AzureLoginView} from '../src/screens/auth/';

// CONSTANT
const CREDENTIAILS = {
client_id: '--------------------------',
client_secret: '--------------------',
scope: 'User.ReadBasic.All Mail.Read offline_access'
};

export default class azureAuth extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
this.state = {
displayName : "Nan",
mail : "",
id : ""
};
    this.azureInstance = new AzureInstance(CREDENTIAILS);
this._onLoginSuccess = this._onLoginSuccess.bind(this);
  }

  _onLoginSuccess(){
    this.azureInstance.getUserInfo().then(result => {
console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
});
this.azureInstance.getUnreadEmails().then(result =>{
console.log(result);
}).catch(err =>{
console.log(err);
});

this.azureInstance.getNumberOfUnreadEmails().then(result =>{
console.log(result);
}).catch(err =>{
console.log(err);
});
  }

render() {
return (
<AzureLoginView
azureInstance={this.azureInstance}
loadingMessage="Requesting access token"
onSuccess={this._onLoginSuccess}
/>
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
paddingTop: 23
},
baseText: {
fontFamily: 'Cochin',
},
titleText: {
fontSize: 20,
fontWeight: 'bold',
},
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('azureAuth', () => azureAuth);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getNumberOfUnreadEmails()
{
return this.getUnreadEmails().value.length();
}
```

you've just forgotten to add this. before the method invokation
Besides you can also use the following syntax:

```
getNumberOfUnreadEmails = () => this.getUnreadEmails().value.length();
```

It does not only shortens your code, but you can also remove the bindings in this case

Comment: thank you, please can u explain why i can remove the binding in this case ?

Comment: I'd recommend to read the section "Main benefit: No binding of ‘this’" in the following article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26
If you still will have some questions, please, ask
One more useful link: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9851

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `this.getUnreadEmails()`

```
getNumberOfUnreadEmails() {
   return this.getUnreadEmails().value.length();
}
```

Let me know if it works!